# Node GET request is hanging unable to finish the request and the page keep loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

SOLVED

I am currently building an app with Node - Express - MongoDB - ejs.

I have a books router that should render the books ejs file and books list from MongoDB.
Here's the `books.js` code:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

router.route("/").get(async (req, res, next) => {
  const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
  const dbName = "Library";
  let client;
  try {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const books = await db.collection("books").find().toArray();

    res.render({
      title: "Books",
      books,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

It is supposed to get the data from the MongoDB and send it back to the books page instead I get this error
`{ "code": "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE" }`

Answer (score 1):

You define a function called `mongo` but then you *never call it*.

Since you never call it, you never call `res.render`.

Even if you did call it, in the `catch` branch you never send an error response either.

It looks like you intended it to be an IIFE but forgot the `()` afterwards. There's no need for that though, you can just make the function you pass as the second argument to `get()` `async` instead.

```
router.route("/").get(async (req, res) => {
    const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    const dbName = "Library";

    try {
        const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        const books = await db.collection("books").find().toArray();

        res.render({
            title: "Books",
            books,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({error: err})
    }  
});
```

Comment: Thanks Solved it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not calling your async mongo function. You are only declaring your function. You need to call it by placing `()` after your declaration like so:

```js
(async function mongo() {
    // Your code
})();
```

So applying that change to your code would result in the following:

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

/* GET Books page. */
router.route("/").get((req, res, next) => {
  const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
  const dbName = "Library";
  (async function mongo() {
    let client;
    try {
      client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
      const db = client.db(dbName);
      const books = await db.collection("books").find().toArray();

      res.render({
        title: "Books",
        books,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })();
});


module.exports = router;
```

Because of this your request would indeed timeout as the code within the async function is not called.

Hope this answer was helpful

Comment: Also: you can also make the arrow function async instead of creating a async IIFE.

Comment: Thanks Solved it.